# Getting the Ambari SNMP setup - plugin to monitor Dynatrace

Tags: python, snmp, ambari, snmp-trap, dynatrace

Is there a way to write a plugin (python) to allow Dynatrace to monitor logs (ambari-alerts.log) from Ambari?

Something like this: https://github.com/apache/ambari/tree/trunk/contrib/alert-snmp-mib

Also take a look at this sample code: https://github.com/Dynatrace/dynatrace-api/blob/master/snmp/IBMDataPower/IBMDataPower.py This is to use the device id and the parameter names to poll SNMP and get the metrics.

I need some help and starters on getting the logs from Ambari and allowing it be monitored by Dynatrace. The plugin should generate an access code. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dynatrace WebUI, when you go to "Settings - Monitoring - Monitored Technologies" you should have a button "Add new monitoring technology", which will provide various options to add plugins with new monitoring functionality.

One of them is "Add OneAgent plugin", wihch allows to write python based plugins for retrieving monitoring data from any source and providing it to Dynatrace for charting/alerting/.... See the Plugin SDK guide at https://dynatrace.github.io/plugin-sdk/readme.html

Another one is "Add integration with API", which describes REST interfaces for sending custom metrics, which is easier to doe than a full-blown plugin. The Documentation at https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/shortlink/section-api provides details about this approach.

See